# Check a topology

Tags: general-topology

Hello I am starting my topology studies, and I am having difficulties with this exercise

Let $\infty \in X$ be a given element in a set. Check that $\tau = \{ A \subset{X}|  \infty \not\in A  $ or $X-A$ is finite $\}$
defines a topology on $X$.

I have to check that:

1. $\varnothing$ and $X$ are open sets
2. The union of any number of open sets is an open set
3. The intersection of two open sets is an open set.

I don't know how to check it

Thanks

Comment: Some of these are easier than others. Did you try showing 1? That should be nice and mechanical.

Comment: I have problems with 2 and 3

Comment: @Mathcristh80: Start with (3). Let $U$ and $V$ be open sets. There are two cases: $\infty$ is in both $U$ and $V$, or $\infty$ is not in at least one of $U$ and $V$. Treat them separately; the second is **very** easy, and the first isn’t much harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a space $X$ with a distinguished point $\infty$.

Let $\tau$ be a topology (using the set of open sets definition) is defined as follows:

$$ \tau = \{ A \mathop| A \subset X \land (\infty \notin A \lor |X-A| \;\text{is finite}) \} $$

Let's check that condition 1 holds.

$\varnothing$ is an open set because $\infty$ is not in it.

$X$ is an open set because $|X-X|$ is empty and thus finite.

Let's check that condition 2 holds.

Let $F$ be a family of open sets. Suppose none of them contain $\infty$, then $\bigcup F$ also doesn't contain $\infty$ and is therefore open.

Suppose at least one element of $F$ contains $\infty$, let's pick one of them and call it $F_0$. Since $F_0$ is open and contains $\infty$ that means that $X-F_0$ is finite. $X-\bigcup F $ is necessarily a subset of $X-F_0$ and is therefore also finite. Therefore $\bigcup F$ is open.

Let's check that condition 3 holds.

Suppose we have two open sets $A$ and $B$.

If $A$ or $B$ or both fail to contain $\infty$, then $A \cap B$ also fails to contain $\infty$ and is therefore open.

If $|X-A|$ is finite and $|X-B|$ is finite then $|(X-A) \cup (X-B)|$ is finite and thus $|X - (A \cap B)|$ is finite. Therefore $A \cap B$ is open.